# Sitefinity 9.2 MVC 5 Feather and Ninject - Error loading module, another module with the same name has already been loaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, sitefinity-feather

Please see attached screenshots and code if that makes it easier (at the bottom of this http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/developing-with-sitefinity-/sitefinity-8-2-to-9-upgrade-error#HlX3NsE3622pWP8AAERlJg post)

I have tried all the methods listed above and the workaround, but still keep getting the same issue.

This happens when I trigger changes(activate/deactivate) a module in Sitefinity/Administration/ModulesAndServices

The progress bar (green) goes into a loop and refreshing the page gives me this:

Error loading Ninject component ICache
No such component has been registered in the kernel's component container.

Suggestions:
 1) If you have created a custom subclass for KernelBase, ensure that you have properly
    implemented the AddComponents() method.
 2) Ensure that you have not removed the component from the container via a call to RemoveAll().
 3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.

And in the error logs for sitefinity I get:

Message : Error loading module 'YourPackage.YourModule' of type YourModule
Another module (of type YourModule) with the same name has already been loaded
Suggestions:
  1) Ensure that you have not accidentally loaded the same module twice.
  2) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure you have not manually loaded a module
     that may be found by the module loader.

Have followed the article: http://docs.sitefinity.com/feather-use-constructor-dependency-injections
and the workaround too: https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather/issues/2580

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is this a custom module that is failing? Any code from it that we can see ... particularly the Install method

Comment: @VeselinVasilev: Yes, I have provided code / screenshots here at this link... http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/developing-with-sitefinity-/sitefinity-8-2-to-9-upgrade-error#HlX3NsE3622pWP8AAERlJg

Please let me know if you need futher info.